# Gravar log das exceções do sistema utilizando application Events

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou querendo gravar em um arquivo texto qualquer exceção que acontecer no sistema.

Estou utilizando o componente `Application Events` da paleta additional.

Abaixo segue o exemplo do codigo:

```
procedure TfmPrototipo.ApplicationEventsException(Sender: TObject; 

E:Exception);
var
  NomeArquivo: string;
  Arquivo: TextFile;

begin

  NomeArquivo := ChangeFileExt(Application.Exename, '.log');
  AssignFile(Arquivo, NomeArquivo);
  if FileExists(NomeArquivo) then 
    Append(arquivo) 
  else 
    ReWrite(arquivo); 
  try 
    WriteLn(arquivo, 'Data: '+ DateTimeToStr(Now));
    WriteLn(arquivo, 'Erro: ' + E.Message );
    WriteLn(arquivo, '------------------------------------------- ');
    Application.ShowException(E);
  finally 
    CloseFile(arquivo); 
  end;

end;
```

O problema que em algumas telas do sistemas é utilizado o 
`try - except`, o mesmo apresenta a mensagem e não chama o evento `onException` do componente.

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento de Delphi especificamente, mas de modo geral o `Application Events` é um capturador global de exception não tratados pelo sistema, ou seja, os que vão gerar crash no sistema, os problemas não conhecidos no desenvolvimento. Já os erros onde você utiliza o `try - except`, são erros que você já previu no desenvolvimento e possivelmente os tratou de alguma forma, então se essa exception não for propagada, não vai ser capturada pelo `Application Events`. Então se apesar de tratar a exceção você quiser fazer log das mesma você deve faze-lo no `except` do `try - except`.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma unit com o código que faz o log e chama ele do `try...Except` que trata o erro e não faz um `raise`.

Exemplo:

```
procedure FazLogException(NomeArquivo: string; E:Exception);
var
  Arquivo: TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(Arquivo, NomeArquivo);
  if FileExists(NomeArquivo) then 
    Append(arquivo) 
  else 
    ReWrite(arquivo); 
  try 
    WriteLn(arquivo, 'Data: '+ DateTimeToStr(Now));
    WriteLn(arquivo, 'Erro: ' + E.Message );
    WriteLn(arquivo, '------------------------------------------- ');
  finally 
    CloseFile(arquivo); 
  end;
end;
```

Agora basta chamar no lugar onde estava o `try...Except`:

```
try
  b := 0;
  a := 12 div b;
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    FazLogException(ChangeFileExt(Application.Exename, '.log'), E);
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Caputo ele mencionou na questão que o sistema já faz assim e não levanta a `exception`. Então usar um `raise` seria mudar o comportamento do programa.

Comment: Não tinha visto esta parte. Vlw... Removendo o comentário :D